# Passing function with 2 arguments to addEvent Listener method

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

I am trying to pass a function Which has 2 arguments to the `addEventListener` method on specific button but the problem is function executing directly when page loading instead of executing it when some one clicked the button.

I know how to make it work with anonymous function but I need it to work with a specific defined function instead.

```
function changeContent(elem,str){
    elem.textContent = str;
}

var btn = document.querySelector("button");

var p = document.querySelector("p");

var content = "Someone Clicked the Button!";

// add event listener on click to the button 

// version 1 with anonymous function worked as expected

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    p.textContent = content;
});

// version 2 with specific defined function not working as expected

 btn.addEventListener("click",changeContent(p,content));
```

any idea of the reason why second version isn't working and how to make it work as expected.

**Update:**

my intended and important question:

> is there any way to make `changeContent(p,content)` function work
>   without wrap it with a (anonymous) function in `addEventListener`
>   method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it also in an anonymous function

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function() { 
    changeContent(p, content)
});
```

> any idea of the reason why second version isn't working

Because `changeContent` is intermediate called because you're passing arguments to it (with the round brackets). In general you could pass a function to a function in two ways:

1. Only the name, e.g. `passFunction(changeContent);`
2. Wrap in a (anonymous) function, as shown above `passFunction(function() { changeContent( ...);} );`. The anonymous function isn't called intermediately, because you aren't passing parameters to it.

> can you explain this point changeContent is intermediate called

If you pass arguments to a function, it's called. If you wrap it in an (anonymous) function, without passing arguments to the (anonymous) function, the (anonymous) function isn't called and hence also not the wrapped function.

> is there any way to make it work without wrap it with a (anonymous) function

Use the `.bind` function. The first argument is the value of `this`. So you need 3 parameters for this case:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",changeContent.bind(this, p, content));
```

For more info, see the [docs of .bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: can you explain this point changeContent is intermediate called

Comment: I understand that you can't pass function to another function if it called like that `functionName(functionName(argument1,argument2))` 
is it right?

Comment: it should be like that without the round brackets 
`functionName(functionName)`

Comment: yes indeed. If you pass arguments (round brackets) to a function, it's called. Updated the answer.

Comment: yes now if you pass it with round brackets  it will pass a return value of the called function 

and if you pass it without  round brackets it will pass only the definition of the function without calling it until the event is triggered.

Comment: indeed. And because we aren't passing the round brackets to the (anonymous) function, the (anonymous) function isn't called intermediately

Comment: thanks alot.

is there any way to make it work without wrap it with a (anonymous) function.

Comment: yes, it's more advanced. Added to the answer. Please fire new question in a new question ;)

Comment: worked ! I didn't understand it will but i think it makes changeContent function object work as a wrap anonymous function by using the `this` argument. 

anyway thanks it helped me so much.